# Parametrize $D = \left\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2+z^2=1; (x-1)^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=1 \right\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to find a parametrization in terms of $t$ (one variable) for $$D = \left\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2+z^2=1; (x-1)^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=1 \right\}$$
I can only use cartesian coordinates. I've tried to do $y^2=-(x-1)^2-(z-1)^2$ and replace it on the first condition, so $x=-z+1$. But I'm not sure about that...I'm stuck. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $D$ is the intersection of two spheres. What might the resulting curve be?

Comment: In your $y^2=...$ you forgot $+1$, so $x=-z+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the two constraint equal to each other yields 
\begin{align}
y^2= 1-x^2-z^2= 1-(x-1)^2-(z-1)^2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  z= -x-1.
\end{align}
Plug the new constraint back into one of the old constraints, you get
\begin{align}
1=x^2+y^2+(x+1)^2 = 2\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+y^2+\frac{1}{2}\ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}+\frac{y^2}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2}= 1.
\end{align}
This can be easily parametrized using cosine and sine. In particular, we have that
\begin{align}
x=\frac{1}{2}\cos t-\frac{1}{2}, \ \ y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin t
\end{align}
gives a parametrization. Lastly, since $z= -x-1$, then we see that
\begin{align}
z = -\frac{1}{2}\cos t-\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}

Remark: It should be clear that the intersection is a circle, but when projected down onto the $xy$-plane you will get an ellipse (as remarked by A.G.).

Comment: I didn't understand this passage:

$$2\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+y^2+\frac{1}{2}\ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}+\frac{y^2}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2}= 1$$

Please, could you explain it?

Comment: I wanted to write the equation in the standard ellipse form.

Comment: Sorry, I meant about the denominators, because I got:

$$1=2\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+y^2+\frac{1}{2}\ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}+\frac{y^2}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2}+1= 1$$

dividing the left side for 2.

Comment: I moved the $\frac{1}{2}$ to the other side then divided both sides by $\frac{1}{2}$. Also, I don't understand how you got your implication.

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake here! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I would use your idea.

By the difference of both equations,
\begin{equation}
x^2 + z^2 - (x-1)^2 - (z-1)^2 = 0 \iff z = 1 - x.
\end{equation}
Then, it suffices to find $y$ in terms of $x$ and we will use the parameter $t = x$. Replacing $z = 1-x$ into the second equation,
\begin{equation}
(x-1)^2 + y^2 + x^2 = 1 \implies y = \pm \sqrt{1 - x^2 - (x-1)^2} = \pm \sqrt{2x(1-x)}.
\end{equation}
This last equation restrict your $x$ values so that $x\in[0,1]$, and your set will be
\begin{equation}
D = \left\{(t,\pm \sqrt{2t(1-t)},1-t)\;:\;t\in[0,1]\right\}.
\end{equation}
*If I am not wrong, the intersection $D$ is a circumference. Maybe it would better to solve the exercise changing the coordinates to spherical.*

Comment: A substitution in the end $t=\sin(u)^2$ with $u\in[0,\pi/2]$ remove the square root, then followed by $u\in[0,\pi]$ remove the $\pm$. This gives $\{sin^2(u),\frac{sin(2u)}{\sqrt 2},cos^2(u),\ u\in[0,\pi]\}$, which is the same than Jacky Chong's.

Answer (score 0):

Just outline for major steps.

**Method 1:** As you did, express $y^2=1-(x-1)^2-(z-1)^2$ to find that $x+z-1=0$. It is the plane where the curve belongs to. Substitute $x=-z+1$ to get an equation for ellipse in $x,y$. It is the projection of the curve onto $xy$-plane. Parameterize the ellipse by $t$ (via scaled $\sin t$ and $\cos t$) and get the last coordinate from $x+z-1=0$.

**Method 2**: Rotate everything around $y$-axis by the angle $\pi/4$, so that in the new coordinates the center of the second sphere becomes $(0,0,\sqrt{2})$. Then the curve is a simple circle in the plane $z=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. Parameterize it and rotate back.